# How do I delay video from the raspberry pi camera module and output it through hdmi?

Tags: video, vlc

I would like to have my camera module take video, delay that video for 15 seconds, and then have it sent through the HMDI cable to a monitor.

I am new to Raspberry Pi's and figured the best way to learn would be by jumping right in... and I got a little lost.

I successfully installed rasberrian, and enabled the camera, and attempted to use raspivid but it didn't seem to have any way to introduce a delay.

I was recommended to try VLC for streaming video, and I installed it and again couldn't find a way to delay video with it.

It might help to mention that I don't need to save the video, just delay it by 15 seconds and have it show on the screen, but saving video is a feature I may want in the future.
If at all possible I would like to avoid sending the video over the internet, but if it's required I can do it.

I am not totally new to bash, but extra explanation will go a long way towards helping me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/rom1v/delay.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some sort of explanation as to how to use that?

Comment: There is an example at the end of the page of delaying a video stream.  Basically you pipe the video stream into the delay program, which delays it, and it then pipes it to your display program.

Comment: That example seems pretty straightforward. How would you install this so that the delay command would work though?

Comment: @joan I would like to accept your comment as an answer as I am pretty sure this is exactly what I need but I have no idea how to get the delay command to work within my rasberrian shell.

Is it as simple as downloading all the files? Do they need to be stored somewhere specific? Thanks.

Comment: General proviso.  It's your responsibility to only download content from sites you trust.  Download the zip to the Pi.  unzip delay-master.zip.  cd delay-master. make.  If you want to make delay globally accessible sudo cp delay /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.